# Display YTD Value on SQL Reporting using OLAP

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, reporting, olap

YTD Value works fine on Excel but not the report using the same OLAP.
This report is production and I need to fix today. I appreciate your help!!

For exmaple,

There are sales in 2012.

Jan

```
Apple  $100
Orange $200
```

Feb

```
Apple $50
Banana $300
```

When I specify Month for Feb, on excel, it doesn't show Orange but Grand Total is correct. But it simply summary them on SQL Report.

Result on excel

```
Apple   $150
Banana  $300
Grand Total $650
```

Result on SQL Report

```
Apple   $150
Banana  $300
Grand Total $450
```

This is my YTD Calculation.

```
Name: [YED Amount]
Expression: AGGREGATE(YTD(), [Measures].[Amount])
```

My MDX for report

```
    SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Variance], [Measures].[Amount], [Measures].[YTD Amount],
 [Measures].[YTD Budget], [Measures].[YTD Variance], [Measures].[Budget] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { 
([MF - Statement Account].[Major Category].[Major Category].ALLMEMBERS * [MF - Statement Account].
[Mid Category].[Mid Category].ALLMEMBERS * [MF - Statement Account].[Acocunt Name].[Acocunt 
Name].ALLMEMBERS * [MF - Vendor].[Payee].[Payee].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, 
MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@MFTimeMonth, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( 
SELECT ( STRTOSET(@MFTimeYear, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( 
STRTOSET(@MFBranchBranchName, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Cube Accounting BU Budget Variance]))) 
WHERE ( IIF( STRTOSET(@MFBranchBranchName, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@MFBranchBranchName, 
CONSTRAINED), [MF - Branch].[Branch Name].currentmember ), IIF( STRTOSET(@MFTimeYear, 
CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@MFTimeYear, CONSTRAINED), [MF - Time].[Year].currentmember ), IIF( 
STRTOSET(@MFTimeMonth, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@MFTimeMonth, CONSTRAINED), [MF - Time].
[Month].currentmember ) ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, 
FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

My formula to show the grand total on the report

```
=Sum(Fields!YTD_Amount.Value)
```